# unknown error using LayoutParams of android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

i've been trying to ensure 2 columns of buttons that are created are of the same height but of no hope.

i tried using the LayoutParams but when i run, the display became blank. There are no error but it display nothing.

*note the text of by button are from a database & both column's text are of different length

my code:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnSize = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btnSize.height = 50;
    btnSize.width = 50;

    //add table row per title
    for(i=0;i<aList.size();i++)
    {
        // ================== normal ================= //
        //create table row
        TableRow trN = new TableRow(this);
        trN.setId(1000+i);
        trN.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //add data to table row
        Button btA = new Button (this);
        btA.setId(2000+i);
        btA.setText(aList.get(i).toString());
        btA.setTextSize(15);
        btA.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btA.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        btA.setOnClickListener(this);
        btA.setSingleLine(false);
        btA.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
        btA.setLayoutParams(btnSize);

        Button btB = new Button (this);
        btB.setId(3000+i);
        btB.setText(bList.get(i).toString());
        btB.setTextSize(15);
        btB.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btB.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        btB.setOnClickListener(this);
        btB.setSingleLine(false);
        btB.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
        btA.setLayoutParams(btnSize);

        trN.addView(btA);
        trN.addView(btB);

        tableConv.addView(trN);
    }//for
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend assigning a fixed size to the table rows (and please convert from dp rather than hardcoding pixels!) and then setting the height of each button to MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: Hi @dsandler could you specify what you mean ? I've tried to do it but to no hope.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnSize = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

with this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams btnSize = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and also replace this :

```
 trN.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

with:

```
trN.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams (TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: hi @android_hungry ,er... sorry it doesnt work.. as the 1st column have longer data...

Comment: it shows... but because column1 is longer, so column2 is push out of vview

Comment: use # distribute weights evenly  in ur layout

Comment: what do you mean ? i have a android:stretchColumns="*" at my TableLayout in my xml, but i guess its not what you mean ?

Comment: try this: android:stretchColumns="1"